# UITableView separator color changing when cell selected

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I've created a UITableView and have a problem with the separator. I customized it so that it appears gray and without inset :

```
self.tableView.separatorInset = .zero
self.tableView.separatorColor = AppColors.separatorColor
```

I also tried with an image :

```
self.tableView.separatorInset = .zero
tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.singleLine
tableView.separatorColor = UIColor(patternImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "thin_divider"))
```

**Problem** : When a row is selected, the separator becomes white. I played with **didSelectRowAt**, **didDeselectRowAt** and **didHighlightRowAt** but nothing to do, it stays white when the cell is selected. See the example below (last cell is selected on this example)...

[image: example of the problem]

Comment: Are you sure it's the separator and not just a 1 pixel gap between the tableview and the next view? Because on your image, it is only showing after the last cell, not after each one.

Comment: @smeshko yeah sure, because on the image i've selected the last cell, but if I select any other cell, the separator becomes also white

Comment: @Mrunal yep thanks, it solves the problem but no more highlighting of the cell when it's pressed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code line in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`method

```
[cell setSelectionStyle: UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
```

This will set none as the selection style (default value for this property is `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue`).

For cell highlight part, use below code in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell setHighlighted: NO];
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

Hope this helps.